# How to use PHP's glob function to grab directories without the output of path?

Tags: php, glob

I've noticed something interesting about PHP's glob function.

When I do

```
$directories = glob('*', GLOB_ONLYDIR);
echo json_encode($directories);
```

the function will return a bunch of folders's names in a json array, great!

But when I do

```
$directories = glob('./img/works/*', GLOB_ONLYDIR);
echo json_encode($directories);
```

the function will return a bunch of folder's names with the path like ones shown below:

```
[".\/img\/works\/123",
 ".\/img\/works\/234",
 ".\/img\/works\/345",
 ".\/img\/works\/456"]
```

Is this normal? If it is, how can I get the glob function to output only the names of the folders?

A relevant question will be: Is there a way to use GLOB_NOESCAPE GLOB_ONLYDIR flags at the same time when calling the glob function?

Answer (score 3):

Yes the behavior is as it should be! You could do something like this if you want, to only get the dir name:

```
$directories = array_map("basename", glob('./test/*', GLOB_ONLYDIR));
echo json_encode($directories);
```

**EDIT:**

Yes you can use multiple flags with glob, it's that simple:

```
$directories = array_map("basename", glob('./test/*', GLOB_ONLYDIR | GLOB_NOESCAPE));
```

Comment: Sweet! A relevant question will be: Is there a way to use GLOB_NOESCAPE GLOB_ONLYDIR flags at the same time when calling the glob function?